# Setter function and setState

Tags: reactjs

I have seen the following code:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
  }

  set name(newValue: string) {
    this.setState({ name: newValue });
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this.state.name
  }
}
```

The setter function puzzles me. Could anyone tell me when the setter function is called? Will it be called by `this.setState({ name: ...`? If so, will it be infinite?

Similarly for the getter function. Will it be an infinite call?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set This seems something easy to test out. I've ***never*** seen this used on a React class component though, so I suspect it's highly irregular, i.e. you'd need to do something like `Welcome.name = 'John Smith'` and this is not a React pattern at all. I'd advise not using it in a React component.

Comment: My question is about the co-existence of the setter function and `setState` (and the getter function and `this.state...`).

Comment: Ok. Do you have a legitimate use case where you'd even try something like this? It likely won't work like you think it might since you very well won't have a reference to any instantiated `Welcome` React component that React is rendering. I.E. In React we don't invoke Components and their constructors ourselves, React does.

Comment: I see this code in a project, which works fine. So I try to understand how React executes it (and solves the conflict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me when the setter function is called?

This is called when attempting to set value to this.name. This is a javascript feature and not related to React.

React ignores all changes to state except when done via `setState`. Changing name using `this.name = 'newName'` isn't normally a valid method of modifying state. All state changes will HAVE to occur via `setState`. In this code, a custom setter method is defined so that `this.name = 'newName'` calls `this.setState`.

There is no conflict in this case. Calling setter method during assignment is javascript feature, React plays no role in it. The setter method modifies the state using `setState` which then notifies react of the change.

The getter function is called every time you try to access this.name. Since the getter function returns this.state.name, it is as-if this.name expands to this.state.name.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate more about the getter function? When is the getter function called?